# Freeswitch: Could not open curl.conf

Tags: freeswitch

I got the following error while using freeswitch `switch_xml_config.c:78 Could not open curl.conf`. This is very interesting, because the offical docs are saying "[There is no separate config file for mod_curl.](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_curl)". So is this file needed, yes or no?

I also looked into the source code and found the error being thrown in the following definition, in `switch_xml_config`: `switch_xml_config_parse_module_settings(...)`. This get's used in `mod_curl.c:1072` in `do_config(...)`: `switch_xml_config_parse_module_settings("curl.conf", reload, instructions);`.
So it looks like mod_curl would like to read a file called "curl.conf".

But as the docs say that there isn't a config file, there is also no info on what this file should contain. Does anyone have any idea what to do? Or should I just create an empty file to suppress the error?

Any hints on what is correct and what to do are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a curl.conf.xml with the following:

```
<configuration name="curl.conf" description="cURL module">
  <settings>
    <param name="max-bytes" value="256000"/>
  </settings>
</configuration>
```

It's in the github repository: https://github.com/signalwire/freeswitch/blob/master/src/mod/applications/mod_curl/conf/autoload_configs/curl.conf.xml

Answer (score 0):

Check if the credential you entered to register a trunk is not wrong